# jQuery UI dialog form submit that is defined with method=POST some how turns into a GET

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I can use some help to understand jQuery and jQuery UI dialog a bit better.

I'm using jQuery v1.8.18 UI Dialog and jQuery v1.7.1 to load an html page that contains a form. The form itself was generated by a Django template. After filling out the form and click on 'Submit', I looked at the HTTP request as seen on the Django server side. The server sees it as an ajax request of type GET with empty GET and POST dictionaries.

The expected result would be a POST with actual submission data in it. Can someone help me understand how UI Dialog changed a POST request into a GET? I'm using Firebug but need some debugging ideas. Thanks.

This is how I created the UI Dialog:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var $dialog = $('<div></div>').load('/friend-request/').dialog({autoOpen:false, title:'Friend Request', modal:true});
         $('#friend-request').click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');
                // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
                return false;});

        });
</script>
```

The element #friend-request is just an HTML anchor. My form loaded just fine into the dialog. Here is the HTML form code that was generated.

```
<form id="id-friendreq" method="post">
    <div style="display:none"><input type="hidden" value="12a94012df543b050d69f46f0012345" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"></div>
    <div class="ctrlHolder" id="div_id_to_user">
        <label for="id_to_user">
            To user<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="15" name="to_user" id="id_to_user">
    </div>
    <div class="ctrlHolder" id="div_id_message">
        <label for="id_message">
            Message<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
        </label>
        <textarea class="textarea" cols="40" id="id_message" name="message">Hi, please add me as your friend.</textarea>
    </div>
<div class="buttonHolder">
       <input type="submit" id="submit-id-submit" class="submit submitButton button white" value="Submit" name="submit">
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't setting the ajax option `type` to "POST" or using a convenience method like $.post(), default is "GET"

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: In this setup, I don't actually call jQuery ajax functions directly. I'm just submitting a a static form that is loaded into a UI Dialog. Is UI Dialog not designed for that? Is an explicit ajax call required to submit this form within the dialog?

Comment: not required at all but you stated that server sees it as an "ajax request of type GET"

Comment: yes, and I'm trying to understand how that happened. The submit button is a plain old <input type="submit"> as you can see in the code.

Comment: form has no `action` so there must be a script submit handler somewhere

Comment: it looks like once a form has been dynamically loaded into a dialog, the form's submit button stops working normally. I still don't understand how but the way around it is to write your own submit handler and do something like a .post(). This is a long the line of what charlietfl said.

Answer (score 0):

The post method is used only if you submit some data.

```
$(el).load(url,data,success)
```

If you are not supplying any data, then it is equivalent to a blank get query. Even on server side, if you don't send any data, there is no way for the server to know if you made a post or get request. Honestly, its just about data, you can send post data with a get query as well

If you must use a POST request explicitly use:

```
$.post(url,{},function(data){$('<div></div>').html(data)});
```

Comment: I edited the question to indicate that I have filled out the form before clicking submit. In that sense, there is data. I guess what I am trying to understand is the mechanism that completely overridden the forms' POST specification. When that form is viewed and submitted on its own (instead of within a UI Dialog), it posts just fine.

Comment: whre are you submitting the form? you don't have any handlers for that in your code

Comment: ok so maybe this is where my gap of understanding lies. I was under the impression that the submit button that comes with my form is enough. The form was loaded in dynamically via jQuery load() but I was expecting, perhaps incorrectly, that the submission is non-ajax.